# Selection in Sectioned List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

If I have a list with multiple sections of heterogenous type (say like a sidebar in a macOS app), how do I keep track of the `$selection`? Here's a simplified example :

```
struct A: Hashable {
    let propA: Int
}

struct B: Hashable {
    let propB: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let allAs = (1...10).map{A(propA: $0)}
    let allBs = (1...5).map{B(propB: $0)}
    @Binding var selectedA: A?
    @Binding var selectedB: B?
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {                                // What goes in selected: ?
            Section() {
                ForEach(allAs, id: \.propA) {
                    Text(String($0.propA))
                }
            } header: {
                Text("A Section")
            }
            
            Section() {
                ForEach(allBs, id: \.propB) {
                    Text(String($0.propB))
                }
            } header: {
                Text("B Section")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the only way around this to create a generic type or protocol to hold `A` and `B`?

Comment: I would make a `protocol` that they both conform to.

Comment: you can also make both `identifiable` and select by `id`

Comment: Is something similar possible while using a `Form` or should I just use a `List` instead?